# CGI page won't load

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I plan to load a Java applet from this page. I can add the code and anything else necessary to the page later, but for some reason I cannot get this page to load. I think it is the `<div>` tags. Can anyone explain to me?

```
!/usr/bin/perl

require "/home/bob/public_html/cgi-bin/cookie.pl";

print "Content-type: text/html\n";

# Make sure the passed date is reasonable
$theTime = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
$theTime = time - $theTime;

&Do_Cookies();

print "\n";
print "\n";

print "<html><head><title>Title</title><link rel=\"stylesheet\"type=\"text/css\" href=\"stylesheet.css\"></head><body>";
print "<div id=\"header\"></div>";
print "<div class=\"content\"><p>CENTER STUFF</p></div>";
print "<div id=\"copy\"><center>Copyright Notice HERE</center><br></div></center>";
print "<div id=\"navLeft\">LEFT STUFF</div>";
print "<div id=\"navRight\">RIGHT STUFF</div></body></html>";

exit 0;
```

Comment: A Java applet? CGI Perl? Have I been transported back to 1999 somehow?

Comment: Ok, look, "it doesn't work" is not a good problem statement. What _do_ you see? What does the error log say? What happens when you run it from the command line? The first thing that jumps out at me---and there are many---is your shebang line. Start there.

Comment: This is very old-fashioned Perl, from the `require` of a .pl file to calling subroutines with an ampersand `&`. You also omit `use strict` and `use warnings 'all` and declare none of your variables That hasn't been good style since at least fourteen years ago when version 8 of Perl 5 appeared. If you're going to use CGI you should at least use the [`CGI` module](http://metacpan.org/module/CGI) in your code

Comment: Shebang line always starts with `#!`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "I cannot get this page to load". Exactly what unexpected behaviour do you see? You you see anything in the browser? What about if you "view source"? Is there anything useful in the web server error log?

Your CGI code looks like something from the last millennium. It would be well worth your while looking at modern Perl web development techniques.

It's hard to test your code as it includes a "cookie.pl" file and I have no idea what that contains. I assume it includes the `Do_Cookies()` subroutine. But if I comment that out and fix the shebang line then I get something that looks like it pretty much works. There's basic HTML error (you close  the `<center>` element twice) but nothing that is going to stop this from working.

Without more information about your problem, it's hard to be any more help.